# Inverse square laws & dimensionality

Tags: newtonian-gravity, gauss-law, spacetime-dimensions

I have been thinking about the famous Inverse square-laws and how they came out to be that way. Gauss's law elegantly describes the square law for electricity to spherical distribution. Now I am tempted to say that the Inverse square laws for gravity and other forces are merely a consequence of the fact we live in a 3D-world. Going from this, can we say however, abstract it may be, that in a 2-D world such forces will drop linearly $\frac{1}{r}$ and in the same manner for higher dimension?

I don't know much about general relativity, so I maybe hasty in my conclusion.

Comment: Without empirical calculation is it possible just theoretically to do it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-square_law
Experimentally no deviations have been found.

Comment: @Mockingbird yeah, makes senses, but aside from my extrapolation into other dimension, can we say that the inverse-square is a consequence of a 3d world or is it something much deeper

Comment: I don't understand why is answered is marked duplicate, the original question is asking a different thing